# toastr não aparece

Tags: jquery

Estou usando um formulário dentro de um modal do bootstrap. O mesmo faz um registro no banco de dados e retorna a mensagem se cadastrou ou não. Inspecionei o elemento diversas vezes e tudo dá certinho. Com exceção de um plugin jquery chamado toastr que não aparece. Como posso verificar se esse plugin (que é um plugin de notificação) está funcionando, já que todas as informações vão e retornam viam Ajax?

Segue o link do plugin que estou usando

http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html

Seguem meus códigos:

aluno.php

```
// continuação do código
success: function (result) {
    var retorno = JSON.parse(result);
    var tipo = retorno[0].tipo;
    var msg = retorno[0].mensagem;

    if (tipo == 'success') {
      toastr[tipo](msg);
      alert(msg);
      $('form')[0].reset();
      $(".modal").modal("hide");
      } else if (tipo == 'error') {
        toastr[tipo](msg);
       alert(msg);
      }
    }
```

cadastraAluno.php

```
<?php

require_once '../class/Conexao.php';
require_once '../class/Aluno.php';

$nome = utf8_decode($_POST['nome']);
$matricula = utf8_decode($_POST['matricula']);
$anosemestre = utf8_decode($_POST['anosemestre']);

try {
    $conexao = new Conexao();
    $conexao->abrirConexao();

    $aluno = new Aluno();
    $aluno->setNome($nome);
    $aluno->setMatricula($matricula);
    $aluno->setAnoSemestre($anosemestre);
    $ano = date("Y");

    $query = "INSERT INTO aluno (nomeAluno, matricula, ano_inscrito, ano_semestre, flag_ativo)";
    $query .= " VALUES ('{$aluno->getNome()}', '{$aluno->getMatricula()}', '$ano', '{$aluno->getAnoSemestre()}', 1)";

    $result = mysqli_query($conexao->abrirConexao(), $query);

    $resultado[] = array('tipo'=>'success','mensagem'=>'Aluno cadastrado com sucesso!');
    echo json_encode($resultado);

} catch (Exception $ex) {
   $resultado[] = array('tipo'=>'error','mensagem'=>'Não foi possível cadastrar o aluno');
   echo json_encode($resultado);
} finally {
    $conexao->fecharConexao();
}
```

As classes Conexão e Aluno funcionam direitinho e o cadastro é feito no banco. O toastr é chamado na seguinte linha:

```
<script src="js/toastr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

É a única coisa que não está funcionando. A notificação não aparece.

Comment: A pergunta não está *nada* clara e é *impossível* responder sem hackear seu computador para ver seu código...

Comment: vou melhorar, colocando código

Comment: melhorei a pergunta brasofilo

Comment: beleza, só um par de dicas, este guia é tipo importante: [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); e fazer um título que atrai a atenção também, sua intenção é fazer um craque ler a pergunta e dar uma resposta, né? Então, cuide do título descritivo e da explicação/código diretos ao ponto; senão aparecem respostas no chutômetro e um monte de comentários pedindo mais detalhes/explicações.... boa sorte!

Comment: Seguirei as recomendações, grato.

Comment: Você já tentou debugar esse `success` pra ver se ele é chamado mesmo?

Comment: Sim Cigano, e ele chama sim.

Answer (score -1):

Tente assim:

```
toastAlert("error", "Sua Mensagem");
toastAlert("success", "Sua Mensagem");
```